# Alteração da versão do MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa tabela em MySQL chamada logou:

**id | idconta | dia**

Essa consulta no Mysql sempre fucnionou no meu servidor:

```
SELECT dia FROM logou GROUP BY YEAR(dia), MONTH(dia) ORDER BY dia DESC
```

Mas agora que o sistema foi para o servidor do cliente, e tudo indica que é uma outra versão de MySQL ou um SQL Server (pode ser? Cliente é da Bélgica, e são MUITO chatos em falar detalhes do servidor deles), essa consulta apresenta esse erro:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'eusoucomp-br-qa.logou.dia' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

O que pode ser? E como corrigir?

Comment: você tem acesso ao banco ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não... Esse é o rpoblema, apenas envio os arquivos para eles, e 10 dias depois eles colocam no ar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do MySQL 5.7 o comportamento padrão do MySQL foi modificado e o modo **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** inserido por padrão. Se você fizer:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
```

E será possível executar a consulta sem erros (mas você precisará fazê-lo a cada sessão).

A melhor solução é fazer algo assim utilizando a função ANY_VALUE():

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(dia) as dia FROM logou group by year(dia), month(dia) ORDER BY dia DESC;
```

Fiz os testes aqui usando a versão 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 e, curiosamente, na versão 10.1.30-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 do MariaDB este problema nem mesmo ocorre.

Comment: Oi, onde eu colocaria essa linha? mysql> SET sql_mode = ''; 
No arquivo de conexão ao banco de dados?

Comment: Se você alterar a consulta e usar o ANY_VALUE() não precisará mexer no sql_mode (pela sua dúvida, você não tem acesso ao servidor). Para alterar esta configuração procure nos arquivos de configuração do MySQL em "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf" ou "/etc/mysql/my.cnf", haverá uma parte do arquivo identificada como _[mysqld]_ e lá deverá estar a linha sql_mode, remova apenas o ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY de lá e reinicie o serviço.